# Segmentation fault after entering in a string from struct

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, malloc

so as the question says I get a segmentation fault every time I try to enter in a name for the customer. This program does compile and works until it gets to the customer name part. I'm not sure if the problem is with malloc. Could anyone show me what I am doing wrong? I've been trying to figure this out for awhile now with no luck. Thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include <ctype.h>  

#define END_OF_STRINGS  '\0' 
#define NEWLINE         '\n'    
#define MAX_CUSTOMERS   100     
#define MIN_CUSTOMERS   2     
#define MAX_NAME_LENGTH 20    
#define DB_ALLOC_ERR    1  
#define QUIT            0  

struct customer
{
    char  *p_last_name[MAX_NAME_LENGTH + 1];
    float amount_owed;
    int   priority;
};

void print_instructions();
int  number_of_customers();
void get_accounts(struct customer *p_customer_start, int
    customer_amount);
void clean_names(struct customer *p_customer_start, int
    customer_amount);
void sort_names(struct customer *p_customer_start, int
    customer_amount);
void print_results(struct customer *p_customer_start, int
    customer_amount);

int main()
{
    struct customer *p_customer;
    int    customer_amount;


    while (print_instructions(), (customer_amount =
        number_of_customers()) != QUIT)
    {
        if ((p_customer = (struct customer *)malloc(sizeof(*p_customer) *
            MAX_NAME_LENGTH)) == NULL)
        {
            printf("\nError #%d occurred in main()", DB_ALLOC_ERR);
            printf("\nCannot allocate memory for database of customer ");
            printf("\naccountable records");
            printf("\nThe program is aborting");
            exit  (DB_ALLOC_ERR);
        }

        get_accounts (p_customer, customer_amount);
        clean_names  (p_customer, customer_amount);
        sort_names   (p_customer, customer_amount);
        print_results(p_customer, customer_amount);

        printf("%c", NEWLINE);

        free(p_customer);
    }

    return 0;
}

void print_instructions()
{
    printf("\n\nThis program allows you to input customers which owe");
    printf("\nyou money (your accounts receivable), and manage these");
    printf("\naccounts in a database.  You will enter the following:");
    printf("\n   Customer last name (1-20 characters)");
    printf("\n   Amount the customer owes (to the exact cent)");
    printf("\n   Customer priority (1=VIP, 2=Important, 3=Regular)");
    printf("\nFrom 2 to 100 customers may be processed.");
    return;
}

int number_of_customers()
{
    int user_choice;

    printf("\n\nGet the customers for the database");
    printf("\n--------------------------------------------------");

    do
    {
        printf("\nHow many customers do you have (%d to %d, %d=quit): ", MIN_CUSTOMERS, MAX_CUSTOMERS, QUIT);
            scanf ("%d", &user_choice);
    } while ((user_choice < MIN_CUSTOMERS ||
        user_choice > MAX_CUSTOMERS) && user_choice != QUIT);
    return user_choice;
}

void get_accounts(struct customer *p_customer_start, int
    customer_amount)
{
    struct customer *p_customer;

    for (p_customer = p_customer_start; (p_customer - p_customer_start)
        < customer_amount; p_customer++)
    {
        printf("\nCustomer number %d", (int)(p_customer -
            p_customer_start + 1));
        printf("\n   Enter the customer's last name: ");
        scanf ("%20s", p_customer->p_last_name[MAX_NAME_LENGTH + 1]);
        getchar();
        do
        {
            *p_customer->p_last_name[MAX_NAME_LENGTH] = getchar();
            p_customer->p_last_name[MAX_NAME_LENGTH]++;
        } while (!NEWLINE);
        p_customer->p_last_name[MAX_NAME_LENGTH + 1] = END_OF_STRINGS;
        printf("\n  Enter the amount owed: ");
        scanf ("%f", &p_customer->amount_owed);
        do
        {
            printf("\n  Enter the customer's priority (1-3): ");
            scanf ("%d", &p_customer->priority);
        } while (p_customer->priority < 1 || p_customer->priority > 3);
    }
    return;
}

void clean_names(struct customer *p_customer_start, int
    customer_amount)
{
    char   *p_fast = p_customer_start->p_last_name[MAX_NAME_LENGTH],
        *p_slow = p_customer_start->p_last_name[MAX_NAME_LENGTH];

    if (tolower(*p_fast))
        *p_slow++ = toupper(*p_fast);
    while (*p_fast != END_OF_STRINGS)
    {
        if (!isspace(*p_fast) || isalpha(*p_fast))
            *p_slow++ = tolower(*p_fast);
        p_fast++;
    }
    *p_slow = END_OF_STRINGS;
    return;
}

void sort_names(struct customer *p_customer_start, int
    customer_amount)
{
    char   *p_inner[MAX_NAME_LENGTH],
        *p_outer[MAX_NAME_LENGTH],
        temp[MAX_NAME_LENGTH];

    for (p_outer[MAX_NAME_LENGTH] = p_customer_start ->
        p_last_name[MAX_NAME_LENGTH]; (p_outer - p_customer_start ->
            p_last_name)
        < customer_amount; p_outer[MAX_NAME_LENGTH]++)
    {
        for (p_inner[MAX_NAME_LENGTH] = p_outer[MAX_NAME_LENGTH + 1];
            (p_inner - p_customer_start ->
                p_last_name) < customer_amount; p_inner[MAX_NAME_LENGTH]++)
        {
            if (strcmp(p_outer[MAX_NAME_LENGTH],
                p_inner[MAX_NAME_LENGTH]))
            {
                temp[MAX_NAME_LENGTH] = *p_outer[MAX_NAME_LENGTH];
                *p_outer[MAX_NAME_LENGTH] = *p_inner[MAX_NAME_LENGTH];
                *p_inner[MAX_NAME_LENGTH] = temp[MAX_NAME_LENGTH];
            }
        }
    }
    return;
}

void print_results(struct customer *p_customer_start, int
    customer_amount)
{
    char   last_name[MAX_NAME_LENGTH];
    float  amount_owed = p_customer_start->amount_owed;

    printf("\n  Here is the accounts receivable customer database");
    printf("\n=====================================================");
    printf("\n   Customer Name         Amount        Priority");
    printf("\n--------------------    ---------    -------------");
    printf("\n          %s         $    %.2f   ", last_name,
        amount_owed);

    switch (p_customer_start->priority)
    {
    case 1:
        printf("1 (VIP)");
        break;

    case 2:
        printf("2 (Important)");
        break;

    case 3:
        printf("3 (Regular)");
        break;
    }
    printf("\n\n******* End Of Customer Database Processing *******");
    return;
}
```

Comment: Run your code through valgrind.  If you're mismanaging memory, it will tell you where.  Make sure to compile with debugging symbols (gcc: `-g` option).

Comment: Please look up what a [\*\*Minimal\*\*, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is.

Comment: Remove * from   `char  *p_last_name[MAX_NAME_LENGTH + 1];` you are declaring array of pointers.

Comment: I don't think getting rid of the * will fix the problem

Comment: I'd really appreciate it if someone could answer my question

Comment: **Could anyone show me what I am doing wrong?** You're not using a debugger to narrow down the problem so that you can ask a question we can answer.

Comment: `temp[MAX_NAME_LENGTH] = *p_outer[MAX_NAME_LENGTH];` is accessing outside the array bounds. Indexes for the array go from `0` to `MAX_NAME_LENGTH-1`, you can't assign to `temp[MAX_NAME_LENGTH]`.

Comment: If you think that's the way to copy a string, you're just wrong. You have to use the function `strcpy()`.

Comment: Strcmp is supposed to be there. I'll change the temp and the other areas that don't  need [MAX_NAME_LENGTH]

Comment: Can someone just show me how to make malloc work with my program? I've been trying to fix this for a while now

Comment: @PaulDann, the primary issue with the name is `char  *p_last_name[MAX_NAME_LENGTH + 1];`. This declares `p_last_name` as an ***array of pointers*** (with 21 pointers) not an ***array of characters*** (with 21 characters). There is no magic to using `malloc` correctly. It allocates a block of memory of the size requested for your use. **You** have to assign the address of the start of that block to a pointer you will use to access the memory. You then must copy whatever information you wish to store there to the beginning address. `p_customer` is allocated to hold `20` customers. Go from there.

Comment: And I don't say that to be dismissive. To "show you how to make `malloc` work" in the context of your program, I would basically end up re-writing your program. That would be of little help to you from an educational standpoint. Much better to learn [**How to debug small programs**](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and talk to the duck... Really, it helps `:)` While at it, visit [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714). Isolate where you are having a problem with `malloc` (add `printf ("in function() at line x\n");` in code)

Comment: Fix. `"line 103: warning: array subscript is above array bounds"` and the same warning at `lines 110, 147, 150, 152, 154, 156, and 157 `. Always compile with **warnings enabled**. That means at minimum `-Wall -Wextra` for gcc/clang or `/W3` for VS (`cl.exe`). Do not accept code until it compiles cleanly -- without warning. You can learn more C by simply listening to what your compiler is telling you than in most tutorials. Let it help you code better. That's what it is there for. All of these are tied back to `char *p_last_name[MAX_NAME_LENGTH + 1];` (you won't have `[...]` with `scanf`...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i believe a start of your problem is here:

```
struct customer
{
    char  *p_last_name[MAX_NAME_LENGTH + 1];
    float amount_owed;
    int   priority;
};
```

with that code you create 21 **pointers** to char.

What you want is character pointer to space that will hold `MAX_NAME_LENGTH + 1` characters

Therefore you would want something simply like:

```
struct customer
{
   char  last_name[MAX_NAME_LENGTH + 1];
   float amount_owed;
   int   priority;
};
```

*I also changed p_last_name to just last_name so to the eyes it reads more logically, but you may call it whatever you like, but to say p_last_name is to imply it's a pointer which is not needed, and it reads poorly*

When declaring or defining variables, you read from right to left,
it would then be an array because of `[]` which is 21 big, called `last name` and it's an array of the `char` data type.

Now the thing with C is that arrays and pointers have something in common, or can often be confused... because they are technically the same thing.  Any array that you define, which in turn allocates space in memory, is nothing more than **a pointer to the beginning of the array**, that's it!

when you do something like `last_name[7]` then the `7` is how many *jumps* from the beginning of the array, which is always known as `last_name` in your case.  The size of the jump is solely dependent upon the data type of the array when it was defined.  In your case it is `char` which is 1 byte, so a jump of `last_name[7]` would be 7 bytes away from where `last_name` points to.

```
For example if the contents in memory where `last_name` points to is    abcdefghijklmnopqrst
```

- then  `char last_name[MAX_NAME_LENGTH + 1];` would define a variable called last_name which is technically a character pointer to contiguous chunk of memory that is `MAX_NAME_LENGTH + 1` bytes *because of data type char* and it is a pointer to the beginning of that chunk of memory.
- `*last_name` is the same as `last_name[0]` which *deferences* the character pointer *last_name* such that it returns the contents of memory which is `a`
- `*(last_name+2)` is the same as `last_name[2]` which is `c`

Also, in

```
int main()
{
   struct customer *p_customer;
   int    customer_amount;
```

this statement `struct customer *p_customer;` creates *one* pointer called *p_customer* that is a pointer which will point to some chunk of memory (hasn't happened yet) that is of the data type `struct customer` which is defined above.  Ok to there.  Then at

`if ((p_customer = (struct customer *)malloc(sizeof(*p_customer) *
            MAX_NAME_LENGTH)) == NULL)`

where you use `malloc` to reserve some chunk of memory for what you are doing, you are really doing `sizeof( a pointer )`

what you should be doing is `(struct customer *) malloc( sizeof( struct customer ))` in addition to correctly defining a 21 byte array of characters called `last_name` in `struct customer`.

It should read out in *English* logically, oftentimes from right to left, if it does not then suspect a problem.  Also when compiling learn to use `-W` it can be your friend and alert you to problems like this.

your original code is likely not allocating or reserving a large enough chunk of memory for the number of characters you type in to store in `p_last_name`.

Comment: Don't forget `print_results()` invoking *Undefined Behavior* by attempting to print the uninitialized `char last_name;` as a pointer `%s`, and the complete failures to validate the return of `scanf` (or handle `EOF`, or *input* or *matching* failures) and admonish against adding spaces around `" -> "` when dereferencing members.

Comment: All right, I understand what I am doing wrong. Thank you so much for the help guys!

Comment: Awesome -- that's progress `:p`

Comment: @PaulDann, I took pity, you may find [The Following](http://paste.opensuse.org/80699767) useful.

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate you all taking your time to help me out